# How to make the library work with the caller script PropertiesService?

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries, add-on

Until Google [extends the import/export API to container-bound Apps Script projects](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2922), I have moved most of my project to a library which can use that API, and then made Google Docs project into a shell that just calls through to the library.

My problem is having the library access the same properties ([`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/)) as the Google Doc project. Since I have existing users of my Docs Add-on, I need to keep using these properties.

In my Google Doc project, I tried

```
$.PropertiesService = PropertiesService;
```

(where `$` is my library).

It didn't work. The library kept using its own properties.

So then I tried:

```
function _mock(obj) {
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[key] == 'function') {
      ret[key] = obj[key].bind(obj);
    } else {
      ret[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

$.PropertiesService = _mock(PropertiesService);
```

Still not working. Trying again:

```
function _mock(obj) {
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[key] == 'function') {
      ret[key] = (function(val) {
        return function() {
          return val.apply(obj, arguments);
        };
      })(obj[key]);
    } else {
      ret[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

$.PropertiesService = _mock(PropertiesService);
```

This works.

---

At this point, I'm wondering:

1. Why did the first two ways not work, but the third way did?
2. Can I expect this to continue working?
3. Is there a better way to have a library access the main script's properties?

Documentation is sparse. There is [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries), but the `PropertiesService` is not mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

**Sharing of resources**

As you are aware, [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#resource_scoping) have shared and non-shared resources. `PropertiesService` is listed under *non-shared* resources, meaning that the library has *its own* instance of the service that is accessed when you reference it *in the library code*.

```
const getStore = () => PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
```

If the function above is declared in the library, it will use the library's resource, if in the calling script - its own instance.

---

**V8 runtime solution**

V8 runtime [does not create a special context](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#adjust_handling_of_global_this) for your code and gives you access to built-in services directly. Because of this when using the runtime, the service can be injected by simply defining or replacing a property on a global `this`:

```
//in the library;
var getProperty = ((ctxt) => (key) => {
    var service = ctxt.injectedService;
    var store = service.getScriptProperties();
    return store.getProperty(key);
})(this);

var setProperty = ((ctxt) => (key, val) => {
    var service = ctxt.injectedService;
    var store = service.getScriptProperties();
    return store.setProperty(key, val);
})(this);

var inject = ((ctxt) => (service) => ctxt.injectedService = service)(this);

var greet = ((ctxt) => () => {
    var store = ctxt.injectedService.getScriptProperties();
    return store.getProperty("greeting") || "Ola!";
})(this);

//in the calling script;
function testSharedResources() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("greeting", "Hello, lib!");
  $.inject(PropertiesService);
  Logger.log($.greet()); //Hello, lib!
  $.setProperty("greeting", "Hello, world!");
  Logger.log($.greet()); //Hello, world!
}
```

In some contexts global `this` will be `undefined` (I encountered this when adding a library to a bound script). In this case, simply define a private global namespace (to avoid leaking to the caller script):

```
//in the library;
var Dependencies_ = {
    properties : PropertiesService
};

var use = (service) => {
    if ("getScriptProperties" in service) {
        Dependencies_.properties = service;
    }
};

//in the calling script;
$.use(PropertiesService);
```

---

**Rhino runtime solution**

Older Rhino runtime, on the other hand, creates a special implicit context. This means that you have *no access* to built-in services or the global `this`. Your only option is to bypass calling the service in the library (your approach #3 is perfect for doing so).

---

**Questions**

1. *Why did the first two ways not work, but the third way did?*

All issues with your approaches boil down to:

1. Resource sharing (libraries have their own service instances)
2. Special implicit context (no external access to lib built-ins in Rhino)

But there is a catch: all 3 approaches *do work* as designed.

First, Approach one *does work* if you specifically reference the `PropertiesService` on `$`. This makes sense as the library is included as a namespace with members mapped to global declarations in the library. For example:

```
//in the caller script
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("test", "test");
$.PropertiesService = PropertiesService;

Logger.log( $.PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("test") ); // "test"
Logger.log( $.getProperty("test") ); // "null"

//in the library
function getProperty(key) {
  var store = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  return store.getProperty(key);
}
```

Approach two *also works*. Binding of the function in the caller script does not change the fact if called *in the library* it receives library context, but if you call the bound copy directly in the calling script, it works:

```
//in the caller script
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("test", "test");
var bound = $.PropertiesService.getScriptProperties.bind(PropertiesService); 

var obj = { getScriptProperties : bound };
  
$.PropertiesService = obj;

Logger.log( bound().getProperty("test") ); // "test"
Logger.log( $.getProperty("test") ); // "null"
```

Now, why does the third approach work out of the box? Because of the closure resulting from the wrapped function capturing the `PropertiesService` of the *calling script* and applying the `getScriptProperties` method. To illustrate:

```
//in the caller script
var appl = { 
  getScriptProperties : (function(val) { 
    return function() { 
      return val.apply(PropertiesService);
    }; 
  })(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties) 
};
  
$.PropertiesService = appl;
  
Logger.log( $.getProperty("test") ); // "test"
```

2. *Can I expect this to continue working?*

Yes and no. Yes, because your `_mock` function behavior exhibits the expected behavior in all cases. No, because `apply` relies on the `getScriptProperties` not being implemented as an arrow function where `this` override will be ignored.

1. *Is there a better way to have library access the main script's properties?*

For Rhino runtime - don't think so. For V8 - direct injection of the service will suffice.